# Thumbnail geration in php is creating unwanted black colour

Tags: php, jquery

I have this image cropping application in jquery + php. Jquery sends the co-ordinates to php and php preety much makes thumbnail out of it. The code is below.

```
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('../../../uploads/'.$dir_name.'/'.$image_name);
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width_img, $height_img);
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, $x_img, $y_img, 225, 225, $width_img, $height_img);
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
```

Everything is correct in the jquery part. It sends all the co-ordinates correctly. Now the problem arises when I crop the image greater than 225 px in width and 225 pixels in height. Unwanted black colour appears as in the image. The image should have been 225*225.. Only the image part, not the black part.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFCEH.jpg):
[image]

Comment: where are `$width_img, $height_img, $x_img, $y_img` defined? We need to see more code

Comment: See $width_img and other parameters come from jquery ajax part. I am very very sure they deliver correct co-ordinates. There's something with php part.

Comment: @AshishNeupane Show it anyway.

Comment: Your problem is with `$width_img` and `$height_img`. They cannot be the same value for `imagecreatetruecolor` and `imagecopyresampled`, as the latter one expects the size of the source image, not the target image, while the first function should be `225` by `225`.

Comment: @jdo: This looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks a tonne.. $width_img and $height_img in imagecreatetruecolor was the problem. Changed it to 225 and 225.. and it fixed..

Answer (score 1):

ive been using this code and it works fine for my thumbnails

```
$resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);
$thumb = imagetruecolor($thumbwidth,$thumbheight);
imagecopyresampled($thumb,$resources,0,0,0,0,$thumbwidth,$thumbheight,$originalWidth,$originalHeight);
```